# Wrap HTML at 79 characters in TextMate?

Tags: html, textmate

I'm working in TextMate with HTML.

For some types of content, if I choose `View > Wrap > 79 characters`, the content wraps at 79 characters.

However, for HTML this does not work, and I don't know how to make it wrap.

Can anyone advise?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having not used TextMate for a while I used to use the "Soft Wrap" feature which wraps but doesn't indent - which is why I stopped using TextMate.  Judging by this open ticket, that still seems to be the case as of 03/03/2011 - http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=4EFB31A8

Comment: Ah, needed Soft Wrap checked as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TextMate is an editor and does not affect how your HTML page will look. When you are setting the wrap option in TextMate you are specifying a personal preference of how you want TextMate to view for you.

To make HTML break at 79 characters you need to add `<br />` (if xhtml) after the necessary number of characters in your page.

Comment: Oh sorry, ambiguous question. I meant 'in the raw text file', not 'in the viewed HTML'.